# Flutter: How to add SVG as Splash Screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

**I want to add Splash Screen to my Flutter app as SVG and I can't find a way**

I didn't tried yet for iOS, but the particular Android ways where you convert it to vectorial asset with: Android Studio, Respresso or SVG2Android don't work.

Also, the dependencies like splash_screen_view and flutter_native_splash can work only with JPG and PNG.

Do someone have an idea why or an alternative?

**MORE DETAILS ABOUT PROJECT**

> @drawable/launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable:splashscreen" android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

> main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ro.adservio.app.adservio">
   <application
        android:label="adservio"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
    
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for help! :)

Comment: is it your SVG is SVG image?

Comment: Yes, it is a SVG image :)
I, also, tried with its converted vector asset

Comment: so you can use flutter_svg => https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg this package and manually delay 3 sec and then navigate to other screen